# how to add legend for scatter()?

Tags: matplotlib

These options do not work...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.random((5,3))

ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],c=['k','r','g','r','b'])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.draw()

ax = plt.axes()
h = ax.scatter(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],c=['k','r','g','r','b'])
plt.legend(h, loc='upper left')
plt.draw()
```

I can assemble use plot instead and write a loop,

```
colors = ['k','r','g','r','b']
ax = plt.axes()
h = []
for i,c in enumerate(colors):
    h.append(ax.plot(arr[i,0],arr[i,1],c+'o'))
plt.legend(colors) ## plt.legend(h,colors) does not work
plt.draw()
```

When if I pass `h` to `legend`, it says

```
  warnings.warn("Legend does not support %s\nUse proxy artist instead.\n\nhttp://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist\n" % (str(orig_handle),))
```

But how can I get this to work with scatter without writing a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to populate the legend with the actual scatter plot, or at least reference what is going on in the scatter plot.  To create a legend, you need to draw it as a separate entity - meaning that the scatter point shapes and colors need to be recreated, for example as a subplot.  This is a slightly more manual approach but should work:

```
colors = ['k','r','g','r','b']
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(arr[:,0],arr[:,1],c=['k','r','g','r','b'])
line1 = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o', color=colors[0])
line2 = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[1])
line3 = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[2])
line4 = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[3])
line5 = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[4])
plt.legend((line1,line2,line3, line4, line5),('color1','color2', 'color3', 'color4', 'color5'),numpoints=1, loc=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - my alternative question was how to build a legend manually; this is it.