# Legends in Matplotlib Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm plotting multiple points in Basemap and would like to have a legend to signify the category that each color represents. However, since I have multiple points in each category, the legend pulls each of those points, giving me multiple entries of the same category in the legend. Is there a way to just show one overall color-category listing?

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=30.,llcrnrlat=20.,urcrnrlon=-160.,urcrnrlat=63.,projection='lcc',resolution='c',lat_1=20.,lat_2=40.,lon_0=90.,lat_0=50.)

X,Y = m(lon,lat)    
m.drawcountries()
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightblue')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0.,90.,5.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,15.),color='gray',dashes=[1,3],labels=[0,0,0,1])
m.fillcontinents(color='beige',lake_color='lightblue')
plt.title('MERRA-Observation Correlations')

for j in range(len(corr)):
    if j == 0 or j == 1 or j ==2:
        m.plot(X[j],Y[j],'o',color='orange',markersize=np.absolute(corr[j])*17.5,label='Prairie')
    if j == 3 or j ==4 or j == 5:
        m.plot(X[j],Y[j],'o',color='violet',markersize=np.absolute(corr[j])*17.5,label='Tundra')
    if j ==6 or j == 7 or j == 8:
        m.plot(X[j],Y[j],'o',color='purple',markersize=np.absolute(corr[j])*17.5,label='Taiga')
    plt.legend()
```

NOTE: I've placed plt.legend both inside and outside the loop with the same results.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be plotting a whole new line for each data point. A scatter plot might be more appropriate: instead of your `j` loop, try:

```
scale = 17.5
m.scatter(X[:3], Y[:3], color='orange', s=abs(corr[:3])*scale, label='Prairie')
m.scatter(X[3:6], Y[3:6], color='violet', s=abs(corr[3:6])*scale, label='Tundra')
m.scatter(X[6:], Y[6:], color='purple', s=abs(corr[6:])*scale, label='Taiga')
```

(untested: I don't have your data).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the legend kwarg, you can retain a handle to the object returned by m.plot. You can then create the legend manually with only the plots you want to keep.

[how to add legend for scatter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017654/how-to-add-legend-for-scatter) has a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: replace your call to `plt.legend()` with this and do it *outside* the for-loop:

```
ax = plt.gca()
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
legend = plt.legend([handles[0],handles[3],handles[6]], labels[0],labels[3],labels[6]])
```

this pulls apart the stuff that's set up by `plot` (`scatter`, etc) calls to be sent to `legend`, so you can see how you might alter legends differently.

xnx's scatter solution also looks good.

p.s. -- this doesn't have anything to do with basemap, it's general to matplotlib plotting.