# Create legend for scatter plot using the label of the samples in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am using scatter plot in matplotlib to plot some points. I have two 1D arrays each storing the x and y coordinate of the samples. Also there is another 1D array that stores the label(to decide in which colour the point should be plotted). I programmed thus far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
label = [0,1,4,2,3,1,1]
plt.scatter(X, Y, c= label, s=50)
plt.show()
```

Now I want to be able to see which color corresponds to which label? 
I looked up the implementation of legends in matplotlib like the one here: 
[how to add legend for scatter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017654/how-to-add-legend-for-scatter) 
However they are suggesting to create a plot for each label of sample. However all my labels are in the same 1D array(label). How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib discrete colorbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar)

Comment: Yes I agree its a duplicate. I had gone through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar but could not relate it to my requirement. I think my question is quite suggestive and would help narrow down the search for answer to this question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a colormap. Some examples of how to do it are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777066/matplotlib-discrete-colorbar).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
label = [0,1,4,2,3,1,1]

# Define a colormap with the right number of colors
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet',max(label)-min(label)+1)

bounds = range(min(label),max(label)+2)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

plt.scatter(X, Y, c= label, s=50, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

# Add a colorbar. Move the ticks up by 0.5, so they are centred on the colour.
cb=plt.colorbar(ticks=np.array(label)+0.5)
cb.set_ticklabels(label)

plt.show()
```

You might need to play around to get the tick labels centred on their colours, but you get the idea.

[image]

Comment: Great! Now instead of showing 0,1....4 on the legend, can I show class0, class1,... class4? I know which number corresponds to which class. However my label array will be [0,0,1,2,4] only. Can I map this to class0, class1 etc?