# How to plot a legend on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have plotted a graph on matplotlib and am trying to create a legend. How do i get matplotlib to create its own legend using the colour markers it has used to differentiate my types of data?

My data is read from a csv file that contains the labels for each type of shape.

[image: My graph]

My code looks like this:

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("AllMixedShapes2.csv")
    X1 = np.array(data_df[features2].values)
    y1 = np.array(data_df[features3].values)

    plt.scatter(X1[:, 0],y1, c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
    plt.axis([0, 17, 0, 200])
    plt.ylabel("Maximum Angle (Degrees)")
    plt.xlabel("Number Of Sides")
    plt.title('Original 450 Test Shapes')

    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I have tried this:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ax' referenced before assignment
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
features_of_labels = ["Circle", "Equilateral Triangle", "Right Angle Triangle",
                     "Obtuse Triangle", "Acute Triangle", "Square", "Rectangle",
                     "Parallelogram", "Seal"]

data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("AllMixedShapes2.csv")
X1 = np.array(data_df[features2].values)
y1 = np.array(data_df[features3].values)
l = np.array(data_df[features_of_labels].values)
```

But i get the following error:
    KeyError: "['Circle' 'Equilateral Triangle' 'Right Angle Triangle' 'Obtuse Triangle'\n 'Acute Triangle' 'Square' 'Rectangle' 'Parallelogram' 'Seal'] not in index"

However if i change `features_of_labels` to `header` and `header = ["Label"]` it works but prints out every label like shown in the next picture.

[image]

Comment: Try `ax = plt.gca()` before that line.

Comment: @bernie i get this error:  `UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.`

Comment: So did you do what the warning told you? You should also have a look at [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812325/pandas-scatter-plot-with-different-color-legend-for-each-point), [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505407/create-legend-for-scatter-plot-using-the-label-of-the-samples-in-matplotlib), and [Question 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017654/how-to-add-legend-for-scatter) and using the aquired knowledge to improve your question. What do you want to achieve and in how far those techniques do not help you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did move the lines but i still get the same error anywhere i move the lines. I tried to change question 1 to my data but i keep getting `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# data for example
y1 = [i for i in range(10)]
y2 = [i for i in range(10)]
colors = ['m','b','g','m','b','g','m','b','g','g']
lables = ['m','b','g','m','b','g','m','b','g','g']

plt.scatter(y1, y2,c=colors, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Match colors and labels，remove duplicates
colors_lables = zip(colors, lables)
colors_lables = list(set(colors_lables))
lables = [lable for color,lable in colors_lables]

# create some patchs of colors
lables_patchs = []
for item in c_l:
    add_patch = mpatches.Patch(color=item[0], label=item[1])
    lables_patchs.append(add_patch)

plt.legend(lables_patchs, lables)

plt.show()
```

And the picture we get:
[image]

You can match your colors and lables,remove duplicates,and create some patchs of colors for your legend.

Further more,you can make some dot of colors for your legend

```
lables_patchs = []
for item in c_l:
    # here, use scatter()
    add_patch = plt.scatter([],[],color=item[0], label=item[1])
    lables_patchs.append(add_patch)
```

And you will get :
[image]

Comment: I showed my attempt in the edit to the question. DO you know what im doing wrong?

Comment: I fixed the answer, and there is an example for you.Hope that helps.